# Building network graph from twitter users by subject

Tags: java, twitter, graph, social-networking, twitter4j

I'm trying to construct a social network graph of twitter users who have mentioned a particular topic.  My strategy to do this goes roughly like this:

1. Query twitter for a topic.  Collect the first 100 tweets that come up and add those users to the graph.
2. For each user:
3. Retrieve friends and followers.
4. Query each friend/follower for the topic.  If they turn up a result (meaning they've discussed the topic), add them to the graph.
5. For each user that was added to the graph, return to step 2 until the desired search depth is reached.

My problem is two-fold.  First of all, this approach quickly exceeds my search API rate limit.    Even with a search depth of 2, it's quite likely that I'll find people with 100+ friends/followers and I am unable to query them all before hitting the rate limit.

Secondly, this all takes quite awhile.  Twitter API is not fast.  In the hypothetical event that I was not rate limited, I could submit the requests asynchronously, but I can't help wondering if there is a more efficient way.

I've tried aggregating the requests into one query per search depth:
topic AND from:name1 OR from:name2 .... OR from:namei

This basically explodes.  I get a connection reset error from the twitter API.  If I copy the query into the twitter web page, it just sits for awhile and then says "loading tweets seems to be taking awhile."

I also emailed api@twitter.com to ask for suggestions / access increase, but no response so far.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to go about gathering this type of information through the twitter API, I would very much appreciate it.  I am currently using twitter4j and java.

Comment: I found a page in which someone tries to do something similar to what I am doing: http://www.babelgraph.org/wp/?p=120

He only skims the very top of the conversation graph without extending the search depth and already runs into some rate limiting problems.  Not super promising, but at least more food for thought.

Comment: The link above from @Alex has been migrated to: https://gweissman.github.io/babelgraph/blog/2017/06/15/the-structure-of-twitter-participant-relationships-in-conversations-around-libya-bieber-rstats.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using a filtered stream for a topic, and building the graph using mentions and retweets? This is quite indirect, and will still be slow, but won't hit any rate limits.

See http://truthy.indiana.edu/ and http://cnets.indiana.edu/groups/nan/truthy

Comment: What I ended up doing was searching a given topic for the most recent posters on it.  Then I select a handful of them from which to build egocentric networks.  Now I can monitor the created network realtime using the streaming API.  Thank you for the input and the excellent links!